# How to use dynamic google map api key in index.html file in angular?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using google maps in my angular application. For that I am using my google map api key by following code :

```
1) //index.html

<head>
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry,drawing,visualization,places&key=GOOGLE_API_KEY"
    async defer></script>
</head>
```

But now my requirements are changed. Now I want to get google maps api key from database.
I tried using various ways but did not get any solution. Is there any way to achieve it ?

Thanks.

Comment: Which database? Note that your key will still be visible to the public regardless of where you get your key from, but as long as you restrict it with appropriate HTTP referrer restrictions, it will be secured. See https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key#restrict_key

Comment: I am using JWT Token based API and I am getting map key from that API with proper authentication. Just I need to use that key in my web project